# Nifi - Anonymous authentication has not been configured

Tags: apache-nifi

Im trying to get system-diagnostics data of my nifi from it self. But i have "Anonymous authentication has not been configured." error. Everything used to work, but after the last restart of nifi, this error occurred. The screenshots below show the InvokeHTTP processor configurations
[part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pUu7.png)
[part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrCjD.png)

Answer (score 0):

By default, anonymous authentication is turned off. To enable it, it must be done in the configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when trying to connect spark streaming to an output port in nifi. First i have this warn in the "nifi-user.log" :

`2022-05-21 12:28:49,465 WARN [NiFi Web Server-100] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Authentication Failed 127.0.0.1 GET https://localhost:8443/nifi-api/site-to-site [Anonymous authentication has not been configured.]`

and an error in the Spark Streaming output saying that Spark Streaming can not connect to Nifi.
After changing "nifi.security.allow.anonymous.authentication" in the "nifi.properties" file in the conf directory to "true" value, the warn and the error are gone and now Spark Streaming should connect to nifi server.